minimal number of lines to cover a grid equals maximal size of diagonal in a grid?
Assume $S\subseteq [n]\times [n]$ is closed down, which means that $(i,j)\in S$ implies $(i',j')\in S$ for any $1\le i'\le i$ and $1\le j'\le j$.
A line in $S$ is either $R_i:=\{ (i,j)\in S \mid 1\le j\le n \}$ for some fixed $i$ or $C_j:=\{(i,j)\in S\mid 1\le i\le n \}$ for some fixed $j$.
A diagonal $T\subseteq S$ satisfies that for every $(i,j),(i',j')\in T$, $i\neq i'$ and $j\neq j'$.
I feel that the minimal number of lines whose union is $S$ equals the maximal size of a diagonal in $S$.
Is this related to some well-known result? Or is there any elementary combinatorial proof?

With your definition of diagonal, this is just a set of non-attacking rooks. Do the diagonal really needs to be a diagonal?

No, it is non-attacking rooks as you said.

Let's represent $S$ by a binary matrix $M$, with a $1$ for elements of $S$, and $0$ for elements outside of $S$.
To begin with, let's forget that $S$ is closed down. Let $G$ be the bipartite graph with adjacency matrix $M$.
The Kőnig's theorem states that the maximum matching equals the minimum vertex cover. Stated in terms of condition on the adjacency matrix, this means that the minimum number of lines and columns needed to cover the $1$'s equals the maximum number of non-attacking rooks we can place on the $1$'s, which is already equivalent to the definition of diagonal you give.
We can show that considering your definition of diagonal is equivalent to considering the natural definition of a downward diagonal $T_k = \{(i, j), i+j=k\}$.
If we have a set of $k$ non-attacking rooks, with coordinates $(a_i, b_i)_{i=1...k}$, then at least one rook has $a_i\geq k$, at least two rooks have $a_i\geq k-1$, ..., at least $j$ rooks have $a_i\geq k-j+1$.
Because the set is closed down, we easily verify that $T_k\subseteq S$. Reciprocally, a downward diagonal clearly gives a set of non-attacking rooks.
